# Failed to scene-update after 10.00s or 0x000000008badf00d Exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting crashes in my app when i m running app without connecting device with Xcode debugger. So when i go with Devices and check i got this kind of report on there.

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
Highlighted by Thread:  0

<Error>: Application Specific Information:
com.healthandsocialecare.touchemar failed to scene-update after 10.00s
```

Good and efficient answer will appreciate. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Look for how to symbolicate a crash.  That should tell you what's happening in stack frame 6( & 7).  Since it seems to be network-related, you should look at sending it to the background.

Comment: Exception Note: SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash) please check below answer with apple documentation link. It may help you for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

Exception code 8badf00d ("ate bad food") indicates termination by the iOS watchdog. The app didn't respond to events on the main queue for some time and thus was terminated — unresponsive apps are terminated by the OS, presumably after 10.0 seconds.

Make sure you don't do any significant work on the main queue (such as networking) or that there aren't any accidental infinite loops in the code.

To debug, use Instruments (or similar tools) to create a trace of the main queue just before the crash and see where it spends too much time in.

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple Documentation [(see the Tech Notes under Other Exception Types)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html), the exception code 8badf00d means

> the application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to
>   system events.

Also it is suggested that whatever is on Thread 0 should be moved to a background thread.

Regarding to **Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)**, iOS won't crash your app if you're running with a debugger and/or in a simulator, therefore it gives you the hint that the app is running `SIMULATED` and **this is NOT a crash**. But you should review the part that causes the `warning` as your app will most likely be terminated if it blocks the main thread for too long.

Hope this will help you.